# Relate a savedsearch in a module in sugarcrm?

Tags: php, module, sugarcrm

I would like to add a savedsearch to a module, but the savedsearch module does not appear on the relationfields list.

What should I change to be able to see module SavedSearch as a normal module in modulebuilder?

thanks!
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a studio.php file inside the metadata folder of the module.
With this, the module will be shown at the module builder and module studio in admin.

But, it will keep giving you warnings and you won't be able to choose the SavedSearch module in the popup selector, because the savedsearch listviewdefs.php has a code to change the "< a>" inside the list in the selector, so in my case, I had to comment it to work.

More importantly, you will have to create the _ file _defs.php for the module to work properly.